# django admin scrapy with UI

Tags: python, django, scrapy, django-cms

i m new to this and struggling to find a way where i can possibly integrate scrapy into my django admin. Meaning there by , 
- able to trigger scrapy spider from my django admin

I have already

- created the spider to collect data
- persisting data into mongodb (so no worries of using wrapper to w.r.t performance)
- have django admin interface able to read that data and display in admin

Now i would like to put a feature where i can see this is my spider and i use the clickbutton to trigger it.

OR alternatively, can you advise if i can integrate sxrapy into djangocms???

I have gone through numerous examples and tutorials but not making sense to me.
How and what should i do? Please share some thoughts. 
thanks

Comment: Why not just integrate Scrapy into Django project without `mongodb` and `djangocms`?

Comment: doesnt matter, irrespective of what db you use.
I want to know how to integrate scrapy into django. What i want is, how to put this  trigger button to start the crawling in the django admin? Can you share any useful information. I have been searching online but no useful tutorial